# MySQL Server using same data in windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, mysql

I have a dual boot (windows 7/linux) computer. I have an NTFS partition to exchange data between them.
I want to install a MySQL Server. However, I don't have another computer and, as I would like to use the data from windows and linux, I want to install MySQL and store the data in the shared disk.

However, the idea makes me cringe. Should this be possible at all? **How** careful must I be with updates? I.e. if the linux updater installs a sqcurity patch, would it be safe to not install it in windows?

Comment: I'm thinking of going with sqlite instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a dump export when you shut down after changes are made, and then import when starting the other OS.  In this case, however, you may consider not having MySQL start automatically.

Comment: This seems a bit too cumbersome... I guess it could be automated, though. Seems like the only really safe solution.

Comment: It should be fairly easily automated...  I think that it'll be less cumbersome than attempting to manage MySQL versions between platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem i forsee, is that..

You  will need to maintain exactly the same version on both linux and windows to share the data..

Updates change functionality, update engines, change data structures..
You really need to maintain this equally, which i think would be a little too much stress..

To avoid the headache, just install it twice :D

Comment: I don't mind just installing it once, same version in both systems. I don't care for security issues because it will be in an isolated network, and there won't be anything critical there. But I fear linux automated security updates can drive me crazy. I just wonder if security updates use to be backwards-compatible...

Comment: I feel that they are.. but no one can be sure with anything anymore..
Oracle has begun a slow death of mysql.. :(